# Laptop power supply trips electrics, only at home. What causes this?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

So my gaming laptop is 4 years old now and ever since I got it, it has tripped the electrics in my house.

Now I'd like to remedy the issue once and for all. At the moment I am using an RCD (or GFI for our American friends) to be able to power the laptop up (it's battery is screwed so it requires constant power from the socket (could be related)).

The use of the RCD does not remedy the house electrics tripping, it merely reduces the chance of it occurring. I plug the laptop into the pre-tripped RCD and then slowly press and release the "Reset" button, and majority of the time this stops the house electrics tripping.

It's all sounding grim, I know, but now I'm looking to remedy the issue, but I don't know where the fault lies. My theories are:
- The fault is with the laptop power adapter, but the tripping only occurs at home, not at work or any relatives or friends houses I visit with my laptop.
- The fault is with the house electrics. The house is almost 100 years old, so it could be the case, but nothing else seems to trip the electrics, although the laptop is the only high powered item that is plugged and unplugged on a regular basis.
- There is no fault with either of the above but I am exceeding the maximum load of my consumer unit with everything I have powered up or plugged in in the house.

The house consumer unit is a fuse board, but also has a MCB rated at 240v 50Hz, 63A Load, 30mA Trip, WES 63/2. The RCD is rated 230v, 13A, A/C only, 30mA Trip.
The laptop charger is rated AC Input 100-240V 3.5A 50-60Hz with a DC Output of 19.5V, 11.8A, 230W.

Is there a way to find where the fault lies, if any, or to work out how to fix this from happening in the future? Maybe a test I can do on the consumer unit or laptop charger?

Comment: You are going to have to explain what a GFI/RCDI is exactly if you want help.  Research is difficult since you use such a common acronym.  I would start with the cheapest item to replace and go from there.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser radiocaf. Each specification can be useful to your potential audience. Add the model of the RCD, with an [edit] of your question. Is the _tripping_ related to a particular use of the computer (e.g. when there is a burst in the laptop request, or it starts some video effect...) or to a particular plug?  BTW even if the house is 100 years old, probably the electric system is younger: is there a  working grounding (earthing) system [usually cable green and yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring#Colour_code)? How many other device are connected and consuming?

Comment: To be clear, is it the breaker opening, or one of those safety things on the socket itself?

Comment: The tripping always happens when switching on the power to the laptop, the laptop is always off when I switch it on at the socket as it's battery isn't able to hold a charge. The breaker at the consumer unit is what is tripping, the RCD (which stands for Residual Current Disruptor) never trips. GFI is a Ground Fault Interruptor. You usually use them on gardening equipment to protect yourself if you accidentally cut the power cord. As far as I am aware there is a sufficient earth running throughout the house. I shall edit my question to include this, and other, responses.

Comment: I know I put an answer already, but maybe this should migrate to: http://diy.stackexchange.com/ or http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Circuit breakers do wear, and trip at lower thresholds.  So every time you trip this breaker, you're making it more likely to trip again.  A power meter, such as a Kill-a-Watt, could tell you how much current is drawn by the laptop.

Comment: If you're tripping a breaker, GFCI won't help with that.  It will just introduce other safety element that can also trip.

Answer (score 2):

You are possibly drawing too many amps on the circuit and the breaker or fuse is tripping. The laptop is probably just knocking the usage over the treshold.

So the easiest way to find out why is turn off the breaker and walk around looking for what devices and outlets are off. Check also any electric heaters. Figure out the amp ratings and add them together. You want to try and have less than the breaker rating (13A), with a little room.

It gets complicated very quickly, but roughly: Amps are watts divided by volts, so a 1200 watt microwave at 120v operating at full power is 10 amps (or 5 Amps at 240).

If your breaker is tripping a lot, figure out why: the wiring gauge used for the circuit may be chosen for the amp load expected, and too much draw can overheat the wiring and cause a fire.

Many years ago, I was living in a very old house and when the breaker tripped from using a microwave, lights would go off across all three floors and the basement. This is because there were way too many things on the same run/breaker (a hazard) and this is an "electrician problem" to be fixed.